# Cambiar de color al top-bar usando data sticky Foundation 6

Tags: jquery, html5, css, foundation

Sucede que tengo un top-bar en mi sitio, y dejo el top-bar fijo usando sticky, y funciona fenomenal, mi duda, es que me gustaria que al momento de hacer el scroll hacia abajo, el top-bar cambie de color, este es el codigo general de mi nav junto con sticky, 2 atributos que no logro comprender del todo y quizas talvez sirvan para el caso es: "data-container-class" & "data-sticky-class", agradecer mucho de su ayuda

```
<div data-sticky-container>
  <div class="top-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><button class="hollow button border black-text" data-toggle="offCanvas"><i class="fi-list"></i></button></li>
        <li class="black-text"><%= link_to "Inicio", root_path, class: "bold" %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu show-for-large">
        <li><%= link_to new_enterprise_registration_path, class: "button bold" do %><i class="fi-torsos-all"></i> Empresas<% end %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En sticky hay tres conjuntos de clases distintas aplicadas según el estado del elemento:

- `is-anchored is-at-top` cuando está "anclado" en el límite superior del contenedor.
- `is-stuck is-at-top` cuando está "pegado" en la parte superior, en alguna parte del contenedor, o sea cuando se hace scroll. También puede tener el valor `is-stuck is-at-bottom` si se configuró para que se "pegue" en la parte inferior del contenedor al hacer scroll.
- `is-anchored is-at-bottom` cuando está "anclado" en el límite inferior del contenedor.

Jugando con esas clases puedes aplicar los estilos que desees según la posición o estado del elemento.

---

Aclarando los dos parámetros que comentas:

- `data-container-class` es simplemente la clase que se le aplicará al contenedor en el cual se desplazará el objeto "sticky", considero que no te sirve de mucho en este caso, pues no cambia según el estado del scroll.
- `data-sticky-class` es la clase que se aplicará al objeto sticky, tampoco te servirá de mucho, pues es estática sin importar el estado o posición del objeto.

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo Shaz! Tu respuesta ha sido impecable! "is-stuck is-at-top" ha funcionado de maravilla, agradezco muchisimo tu ayuda!